# Result from FourierCosCoefficents does not appear to be linear

Tags: fourier-analysis

f3 and f4 below produce the same output (more or less) but 
the coefficient in f3 does not appear to be the sum of f2 and f1 (which it should, uiam).'

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f0[x_] := ( x^2)
f1[x_] := ( -2*Pi*x^2)
f2[x_] := (x^4)
f3[x_] := f1[x] + f2[x]
f4[x_] := (x^4 - 2*Pi*x^2)
FourierCosCoefficient[f0[x], x, n]

Print["f1 coeff=", FourierCosCoefficient[f1[x], x, n]]
Print["f2 coeff=", FourierCosCoefficient[f2[x], x, n]]
Print["f3 coeff=", FourierCosCoefficient[f3[x], x, n]]
```

Output is 
[image]

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: uiam FT is not linear in this sense. It is not [additive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_function), but is [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function).

Answer (score 3):

They just appear in different form, but f3coef is the sum of f1coef and f2coef. To verify:

```
f1[x_] := (-2*Pi*x^2)
f2[x_] := (x^4)
f3[x_] := f1[x] + f2[x]
f1coef = FourierCosCoefficient[f1[x], x, n]
f2coef = FourierCosCoefficient[f2[x], x, n]
f3coef = FourierCosCoefficient[f3[x], x, n]
FullSimplify[f3coef == f1coef + f2coef]
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I think I am missing something fundamental: Inside the parentheses  for f3  (after expanding) is -6  - n^2*pi +  n^2*pi^2 but